# Replacing data values via dictionary with JOLT

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have a jolt spec doing some trivial data transformation.  What I need to do next is replace values with their couterpart from a map.  It looks something like this:

**Static data**

```
replacementDictionary = {
    "1": "Doug",
    "2": "Jake",
    "3": "Raymond"
}
```

and the data to replace:

**Input**

```
{
     "name": "1",
     "address": "123 Fake Street"
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
     "name": "Doug",
     "address": "123 Fake Street"
}
```

If it simplifies anything, there is only one record at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like a "switch/case" to translate your value to the desired string:

**input**

```
{
  "name": "1",
  "address": "123 Fake Street"
}
```

**spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": {
        "1": {
          "#Doug": "name"
        },
        "2": {
          "#Jake": "name"
        },
        "3": {
          "#Raymond": "name"
        }
      },
      "address": "&"
    }
  }
  ]
```

**output**

```
{
  "name" : "Doug",
  "address" : "123 Fake Street"
}
```

Comment: I have about 50 entries so this may be a bit cumbersome, but it's the best solution I've seen.  Thank you.